# Elastic Search Highlight Not Working With Custom Analyzer/Tokenizer

Tags: elasticsearch

I can't figure out why highlight is not working.  The query works but highlight just shows the field content without em tags.  Here is my settings and mappings:

```
PUT wmsearch
{
  "settings": {
    "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 2000,
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "custom": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "custom_token",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "custom2": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "custom_token": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 10
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "document": {
          "properties": {
            "reference": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "custom"
            }
          }
        },
        "scope" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "level" : { 
              "type" : "integer"
            },
            "ancestors" : { 
              "type" : "keyword",
              "index" : "true"
            },
            "value" : { 
              "type" : "keyword",
              "index" : "true"
            },
            "order" : {
              "type" : "integer"
            }    
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my query:

```
GET wmsearch/_search
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string" : { 
      "fields": ["document.reference"],
      "analyzer": "custom2",
      "query" : "bloom"
    } 
  },
  "highlight" : {
    "fields" : {
      "document.reference" : {}
    }
  }
}
```

The query does return the correct results and highlight field exists within results.  However, there is not em tags around "bloom".  Rather, it just shows the entire string with no tags at all.

Does anyone see any issues here or can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by adding "index_options": "offsets" to my mappings for document.reference.